# MvvmCross binding to ImageResource property on an Android ImageView

Tags: android, data-binding, imageview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have been banging my head against a wall on what I thought should have been an easy problem.

I am writing an android application using Xamarin and MvvmCross. I have an ImageView and I want to bind a resource to it. The resource bound would be based on a string property called Function on my viewmodel. A value converter converts it to an int. I'm assuming I should be using the ImageResource property

So I am doing the following

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="ImageResource Function, Converter=MyIconConverter" />
```

However this does not work and I get the following error in the log

MvxBind:Warning: 98.79 Failed to create target binding for binding ImageResource for Function
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 98.79 Failed to create target binding for binding ImageResource for Function
10-21 15:08:27.506 I/mono-stdout( 9440): MvxBind:Warning: 98.79 Failed to create target binding for binding ImageResource for Function

My MyIconConverter is part of my Android application (not in the core project) because it is android specific, it converts from a string to an int, and all it does is return a resource e.g Resource.Id.Icon

Is what I am trying possible, if so does anyone know what I am doing wrong. If it is not possible, how should I be doing it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, but please. if what I am doing is possible, please tell me how to do it this way first before suggesting alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MvvmCross comes with a bunch of pre-built bindings.

You want to use

```
local:MvxBind="DrawableId MyIconConverter(Function)"
```

NOTE: I used the simpler syntax for calling value converters. See *Functional syntax for ValueConverters and ValueCombiners* at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding

For a complete list of built-in data bindings:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bbf9a2ac76e74d9404f4b57036c6e29dfe2cc6c3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs

Comment: Thanks. No more head banging, until the next issue I come up against